# Perform counting and divided per date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Perform counting funding for each company,
divided by year of the date of arrival, only if we have at least two loans disbursed (disbursement date! = null) in the year.

```
SELECT F.Id, P.DatArrival, COUNT(*) AS Number
FROM    company C
INNER JOIN dbo.Prat P ON P.ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN funding F ON F.IdPrat = P.IdPrat
--WHERE 
GROUP BY F.Id, P.DatArrival
```

So i want to know if my query is good and how can i do the other one i mean this one: only if we have at least two loans disbursed (disbursement date! = null) in the year.

Comment: Add schema with some sample data and your expected result

Comment: Can you share expected result set with tables structure and sample data? Just edit the question for this.

Comment: @SurajKumar what you need a schema with the table or what you mean or reault..     i make this new code.   SELECT P.DataArrivo , F.IdFinanziamento,
      COUNT(*) AS NumeroFinanziamento
 FROM dbo.Azienda A
INNER JOIN dbo.Pratica P ON P.IdAzienda = A.IdAzienda
INNER JOIN dbo.Finanziamento F ON F.IdPratica = P.IdPratica
WHERE f.DataErogazione <> null
GROUP BY F.IdFinanziamento, P.DataArrivo
HAVING COUNT(f.IdFinanziamento) > 2

Comment: We need both schema, sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Sreenu131 what you mean..?

Comment: He means, whenever you make any database question you should write: *"This is my data.. **<paste table data AS TEXT not screenshot>**. This is my query at I already tried **<paste query as text>**. This is what I want **<paste what you want your query to output for the data you have already pasted>**"*

Comment: yeah but the tables i have a lots that's why i didn't make the screenshot and i didn't create table i have them already that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the answer thanks a lots and have a good day.

the answer is :

```
    SELECT  A.IdAzienda, P.DataArrivo ,COUNT(*) AS NumeroFinanziamento
 FROM   dbo.Azienda A
LEFT JOIN dbo.Pratica P ON P.IdAzienda = A.IdAzienda
left JOIN dbo.Finanziamento F ON F.IdPratica = P.IdPratica
WHERE F.DataErogazione IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.IdAzienda, P.DataArrivo
HAVING COUNT(F.IdFinanziamento) >= 2
ORDER BY A.IdAzienda
```

Answer (score 0):

The HAVING clause will restrict a set of rows after they have been grouped

```
SELECT F.Id, P.DatArrival, COUNT(*) AS Number
FROM    company C
INNER JOIN dbo.Prat P ON P.ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN funding F ON F.IdPrat = P.IdPrat
--WHERE 
GROUP BY F.Id, P.DatArrival
HAVING COUNT(disbursementdate) >= 2
```

You seem to be translating your pages; I've no idea what the column name is for disbursement date

This query only shows company (f.id?) and year (p.datarrival?) where there were 2 or more non null disbursement dates in the year. If you meant that it should be 2 disbursement dates ever, that's different..

Also, if DatArrival is a date (months and days) as well as a year, then you should extract just the year from it, perhaps with YEAR(p.DatArrival)

Comment: i have my question in italy language if you want to see it..?

Comment: and i make this new code :
SELECT P.DataArrivo , F.IdFinanziamento,
      COUNT(*) AS NumeroFinanziamento
 FROM dbo.Azienda A
INNER JOIN dbo.Pratica P ON P.IdAzienda = A.IdAzienda
INNER JOIN dbo.Finanziamento F ON F.IdPratica = P.IdPratica
WHERE f.DataErogazione <> null
GROUP BY F.IdFinanziamento, P.DataArrivo
HAVING COUNT(f.IdFinanziamento) > 2

Comment: What is the company id? c.ID?

Comment: eseguire conteggio numero finanziamenti per ciascuna azienda, 
 suddiviso per anno della data arrivo pratica ,
 solo nel caso in cui abbiamo almeno due finanziamenti erogati (data erogazione != null)nell'anno
code i made forget the other one:
SELECT P.DataArrivo , f.IdFinanziamento,
      COUNT(*) AS NumeroFinanziamento
 FROM dbo.Azienda A
INNER JOIN dbo.Pratica P ON P.IdAzienda = A.IdAzienda
INNER JOIN dbo.Finanziamento F ON F.IdPratica = P.IdPratica
WHERE f.DataErogazione <> null
GROUP BY F.IdFinanziamento, P.DataArrivo
HAVING COUNT(f.IdFinanziamento) > 2

Comment: Bear in mind that if you delete a question, someone who is helping you may be half way through editing their answer, and it also gets deleted, losing their efforts :(

Comment: i was just make some change that's why i was wanna change it all but i can't that's why.